# Ruby on Rails : Search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search-form

Hello I'm developing a simple search form for my rub application.

I've created an action in an existing controller generated by a scaffold:

```
(rails g scaffold Product name description:text price:decimal)
```

called `search_products` and a view called `search.html.erb`

in the search view I've got the `text_field_tag` where I insert the parameters for the search (and of course a submit button to send them)

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
 <%= submit_tag "Search" %> 
<% end %>
```

when i press submit the page root to the products_path where i found the list of my searched products.

It seems to be a sort of error in my `search_products` action because I receive this error:

> NoMethodError in ProductsController#index
>
> undefined method `search_products' for #

I post my controller:

```
def self.search_products(search)
    if search
      where(["name LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
    else
      all 
    end
  end

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.search_products(params[:search])
  end
```

This is one of my first rails applications so sorry for my dumb errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 def self.search_products(search)
   if search
     where(["name LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
   else
     all 
   end
 end
```

This code is supposed to be in your model code, not controller